# Calling a function that in inside an event from another event outside

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I've been struggling with a javascript problem, which I can't seem to find the solution to solve it.

How can I call a function that is inside an event like this :

```
$('a.buttoncomments').live( 'click', function () { 
    function getComments(productId,revisionId,commentId) { 
        // some stuff 
    }
});
```

from another event :

```
$("#container-comments").on('scroll', function() {
if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight && onScroll === false) {
            onScroll = true;
            nTcommentId = $(".commentId").last().val();
            // call the function here -> getComments(value,value,value);
            onScroll = false;
        }
});
```

When I do this way, it tells me that :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getComments is not defined

Well I think that is all the code required in order for you guys to tell me what im missing!

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define getComments outside of the click event. Currently it is scoped only to that function.

Comment: that's what I tought but I wanted to make sure there was absolutely no way to reach it from where I was, as my javascript level is far from good right now, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, feel free to mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I will once i'm able to. I think you only can 15minutes after you posted the question.